# Can I access my 2nd Hard Disk?

Tags: hard-drive, disk, storage

I've installed Ubuntu over Windows 7 on my laptop, and didn't think about the second hard disk that it had, which I want to use for storage. Now I can't find a way to access it. Is it possible to add it so I can use it for storage, or is it too late and I would have to reinstall Ubuntu?

Very new and inexperienced to Ubuntu/Linux in general, thank you for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

If there is important data on your secondary hdd then I would take caution.

The [likely] reason for Ubuntu not seeing your additional hard disk is because it is not getting mounted, and/or because it has a filesystem of ntfs.

In your terminal you can list all disks with fdisk:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Once you locate the partition in question, you might be able to mount it:

(Assuming the ntfs partition you found is `sdb2`)

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/foo
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /mnt/foo
```